# Index value transfer between views

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

  UIViewController *storyViewController = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryViewController"];
  HistoryDetails *obj = [[HistoryDetails alloc]init];
  obj.currentIndex = indexPath.row;

  [self presentViewController:storyViewController animated:YES completion:nil]; 

}
```

Here is my TableViewController's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and with the selection of cell it will go to another `viewController` which is HistoryDetails.

Now I have a property `currentIndex` in`HistoryDetails` class and I set data to that property which is `indexPath.row`. But in  `HistoryDetails.m` I am not getting the selected index value.(Always getting 0). where is fault in my code.

Comment: What is exactly `HistoryDetails` ? You create a new object: `HistoryDetails *obj = [[HistoryDetails alloc]init];`. What's the link between `obj` and `storyViewController` (the ViewController that you show)?

Comment: May be I made a mistake. Can you please tell me how can I send data to storyViewController(Class: HistoryDetails) with tap of cell.

Comment: `storyViewController` is a `HistoryDetails` object? You need to pass data to `storyViewController`.

Comment: Don't you want to send the item / object **at** the index rather than the index itself?

Comment: ok let me clear. `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is in first `tableViewController`. now if I tap cell then it will go to another `viewController` whose custom class is `HistoryDetails`. now I want to send selected index number to that view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you mean

```
HistoryDetails *storyViewController = (HistoryDetails *)[mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryViewController"];
storyViewController.currentIndex = indexPath.row;
[self presentViewController:storyViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`returns the requested view controller.
 You need to cast the instantiated controller to the custom subclass.